# Ssrs multi tablix merging

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I got a request from a sales manager. He needs a report that can show the sales volumes per department per customer per reason of purchase for a given period.

Since each department accounts for its sales differently, I developed 12 procedures to get the required data. Some departments need to list the items, and some don't.

All good to this point. So when I put my data into the report, I can't make the 12 tablix go together. E.g., the customer tablix will print all the customer's info, and then the department one tablix will show all the sales and so on.

What I would like to see is a tablix that host the data from the first customer, then the department one tablix, then department two tablix, and so on until all departments are done for the given customer. Then move to the next customer and so on and so.

I can't use the lookup since the customer tablix has no relation to the reason in the other tablix; however, they all relate to the customer code.

I try to copy the tablix one into their customer tablix, hoping to see the break in customers and department one complete data set. But I got an error saying the customer table has no relation to the reasons.

The expectation is to see:

````
Customer one
Name
Address 
Phone
Department one: reason 1, reason 2, reason 3,reason 4
Department two: reason 1, reason 2, reason 3, reason 4

Customer two
Name
Address
Phone
Department one: reason 1, reason 2, reason 3, reason 4```
````

Comment: Why not use a single dataset? You can make a union all to the data and use nulls or blanks for columns not exist in other datasets like item

Comment: I was thinking of something like that. I do mask all the fields with the same name at the procedure level. I will update you with the results. I was thinking of adding a parameter to the procedures and create subreports.

Comment: Subreports is the only way with multiple datasets, but it would be my second option. Single dataset is always my first

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In the end, I was unable to make it with the matrix approach. I ended up with a central customer tablix. Then inside the group, I would create a new line for each category, giving them the corresponding label and adding a new sub-report. The subreport would be bound by the customer's I'd to the main tablix. I also had to change all the procedures to use the customer's id; this change allowed me to bound them to the main tablix. Since I already have all the rolling values, I also added a set of independent tablix to summarize the report's beginning.

Not the best solution, but you need to deliver something.